# Merge Numpy Arrays by Two ID's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, data-mining

So I'm trying to use Python to merge two csv files. I am reading them into Numpy Arrays. It's baseball stats, but I have two separate tables. One has Year, Player Name, Salary. The other has Year, Player Name, Batting %, RBI, etc... I want to merge these two numpy arrays so by Year and Player Name. I need both to be the same in the row because players can play in multiple years, but I want the specific players' stats in the specific year.

For example, let's say I have [1985, 'John Doe', $5m] in one array. If I have [1985, 'John Doe', 0.645, 23, ...] then these lines would merge (without duplicating the year and name). However, if it were any year other than 1985 OR any name other than John Doe then it wouldn't match

Comment: Why don't you use pandas dataframe?

Comment: You can use pandas DataFrames and use the `join` feature.

Comment: If you really want a `numpy` solution, you need to tell us about the arrays that you loaded. in particular `shape` and `dtype`.  That said, this does sound more like a `pandas` question.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the data, can only give a general solution.

Since they are csv files, read them in with `pandas` and do a join/merge

```
import pandas as pd

df_salary = pd.read_csv('salary.csv')
df_stats = pd.read_csv('stats.csv')

columns_to_merge_on = ['Player Name', 'Year']

df = pd.merge(df_salary, df_stats, how='outer', on=columns_to_merge_on)
```